# jQuery JSON not showing german umlauts (utf-8 format)

Tags: jquery, json, encoding, utf-8, diacritics

I have a little problem with german umlauts in my browser (firefox ~latest). German umlauts like ä,ö are shown as Ã¤,Ã¶. This Text comes from a utf-8 without bom formatted json file. If I have a look at the file on the server, the text is displayed correctly. This file get's loaded dynamicly by javascript:

```
$.getJSON(PATH_RELATIVE_JSON + fileName + '.json', function(data)
    {
        var json=data[Object.keys(data)[0]];

        if(!isEmpty(callBackName))
        {
            window[callBackName](json);
        }
    });
```

I also have extended the setup with: (prepended)

```
$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"})
```

and also another `$.ajax` variant.

But the result looks not correct to me:

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Connection  close
Content-Length  581
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Date    Tue, 26 Nov 2013 17:25:56 GMT
Etag    "91ce110-245-4ec0564348dc0"
Last-Modified   Mon, 25 Nov 2013 19:30:07 GMT
Server  Apache
```

Why is the **Content-Type text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1**? It should be UTF-8 and may everything would work right...

**JSON**: UTF-8 without BOM

**Website**: UTF-8 & in my file: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

**Javascript**: UTF-8

always happy for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved!!!!

someone gave me the tip to check my apache configuration.

Even with mod_rewrite rights you can change the default charset to UTF-8.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddCharset UTF-8 .js
AddCharset UTF-8 .css
AddCharset UTF-8 .php
AddCharset UTF-8 .json
```

That is my new Charset config.